# Upload File using Xamarin Filepicker plugin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to upload a pdf file using the nuget package filepicker.

I’m able to getting the file name & file local path.
But when I am trying to convert the file to a byte array I am getting an error.

It's my pcl Code-

```
public interface ILoclFileProvider
{
    byte[] GetFileBytes(string path);
}

public static class FileUtility
{
    public static ILoclFileProvider FileSystem { get; set; }

    public static void SetUp(ILoclFileProvider fs)
    {
        FileSystem = fs;
    }
}
```

This is my Droid Project code-

```
public class LocalFileProvider_Droid : ILoclFileProvider
{
    public byte[] GetFileBytes(string filePath)
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    }
}
```

and in my pcl project I'm calling this-

```
var bytes = FileUtility.FileSystem.GetFileBytes(filePath);
```

and I'm getting an error-

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You need to use DependencyService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling the DependencyService wrong. Try this:

`var bytes = DependencyService.Get<ILoclFileProvider>().GetFileBytes(filePath);`

Also make sure you registered it through the right attribute above the namespace in your Android project.

`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (LocalFileProvider_Droid))]`

This line makes sure that the dependency is registered within the Xamarin runtime. For more information on the DependencyService, check out these new Microsoft [docs pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

Comment: yes it worked.
but now am getting an error that
'Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Download/future_of_js_2018_progress.pdf" is denied'.

do you know what should i do here?

Comment: Yes.
Read_External_Storage and Write_External_Storage is checked.